# How to get KIK profile details by username, using the URL?

Tags: api, kik

I want to get user profile details using a KIK URL..

e.g, http://xyz-some-kik-domain/user/[username]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the kik API for getting user details without needing a bot API Key.

https://ws2.kik.com/user/KikTeam

I wrote my self a simple java method to get the information by parsing the JSON Response.

```
public static void getInformation(String username){
    String API = "https://ws2.kik.com/user/";

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(API + username).openConnection().getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        String response = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        String firstName = jsonObject.getString("firstName");
        String lastName = jsonObject.getString("lastName");
        long displayPicLastModified = jsonObject.getLong("displayPicLastModified");
        String displayPic = jsonObject.getString("displayPic");
        System.out.printf("firstName: %s, lastName: %s, displayPicLastModified: %d, displayPic: %s\n",
                firstName, lastName, displayPicLastModified, displayPic);
    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now lets call it by using

```
getInformation("KikTeam");
```

as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use kik-python there is a method `kik.get_user` https://kik.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user.html#users

If you aren't using that, simply make a GET request to the url below

```
    response = requests.get(
        'https://api.kik.com/v1/user/<username>',
        auth=('<bot_username>', '<bot_api_key>'),
    )
```

Comment: How can I get the bot_api_key? I have created a bot in KIK app.

Comment: Also I want to get user details from any usernames across the world and not restricted to my bot account.

Comment: The bot api_key is the api_key listed on the configuration tab of dev.kik.com

Comment: You cannot get access to usernames of people who haven't messaged your bot.